# Testing Exception different than thrown Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, socket-timeout-exception

I have a method that throws Exception. Later on inside the method, there is a conditional checking the Instance type of the Exception cause, namely SocketTimeoutException:

```
public methodName() throws Exception{
  //some code...then...
  try{        
     //code
    } catch(Exception ex){
     if(ex.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
      //Here is where I want to increase code coverage.
      //this part is not covered in the test.
     }
 }
```

This does not work:

```
when(object.methodCall()).thenThrow(SocketTimeoutException);
```

My question: is there any way to increase code coverage by accessing the SocketTimeoutException branch of the code?

Having a Unit test throw Exception will not lead to the SocketTimeoutException, right?

Can I inject the instance type of the Exception to be SocketTimeoutException?

Comment: You should not check the instance of the exception inside of a catch block. Put it in a separate catch block.

Comment: What does the code do?

Comment: @Jens There are a bunch of service calls, about 3. All of them are inside a try catch (Exception ex). I guess I can dig into those services to see how I can cause a SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: It depends on the code inside of the try block

Comment: If I were to review this piece of code, I'd reject it, unless the methods called inside the `//code` part clearly document that they throw a `WhateverException`, with cause `SocketTimeoutException` in any relevant timeout situation. And then I'd challenge these methods for using a weird exception pattern, and your code should be changed to catch `WhateverException` instead of `Exception`.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I totally understand both of your responses from a clean-code point of view. Could you explain other reasons this is a bad idea?

Comment: You rely on undocumented behavior, so minor changes (regarded as irrelevant by the other methods' authors) will break your code.